# Why was my not-an-answer flag disputed? Does that mean these kind of answers are welcome?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, specific-answer, not-an-answer, disputed-flags

I flagged [this answer (10K)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25873563/2530848) recently, and it should probably be a comment. But my flag was [disputed](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5789423). I know it was disputed, because some says "Recommend deletion" and others says "Looks Ok". That's not the answer I am expecting here.

Does that mean these kind of answers are welcome in Stack Overflow? I always thought Stack Overflow doesn't allow these kind of poor quality answers. Is this still the case?

These kind of answers add no value. They should be converted to a comment or deleted IMHO.

> [image]

Comment: Purging comments, as much as I appreciate the irony of putting multiple answers in the comment space on a question where the asker asserts that an answer should be a comment.

Comment: I would argue that this is an answer. The question quotes some statement, and then asks "Is this correct?". "They are incorrect" directly addresses that question. Granted, it is very brief, and would certainly be much better with some explanation. But it's still an answer.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Yes, I know it is a correct answer but not a good answer for StackOverflow. If question asks *Am I doing it right?* do you argue *no* as an answer? It may be an answer, but not a good answer as it fails explaining why so.

Comment: I agree with @Reto, and it looks like your analogy is flawed, Sriram Sakthivel. Clarifying why something does not work makes sense, clarifying why something still works not as much.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel: The question here is if this **is** an answer. Only things that are not answers at all should be flagged. If you believe that it's not a **good** answer, cast a downvote. If enough people agree, it will end up at the bottom of the page. And often the poster will delete the answer anyway once it gets a few downvotes.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Without an explanation, this answer (**"They are incorrect"**) may become useless in case if someone else posts an opposite opinion.

For example, if someone posts a claim like **"They are correct"**, how would this answer help reader to [pick of two opposing opinions](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFCT.png "example")?

Comment: @gnat "this answer ... may become useless" Absolutely - and the tooltip text of the downvote button is *This answer is not useful*.

Comment: @AirThomas downvote I see, sure. [How many?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mOFCT.png "148? 151?")

Comment: @AirThomas  Ofcourse,I downvoted it before flagging. How to handle the cases where some dumb people upvotes it? Does that makes it a helpful answer(as the upvote tooltip text says)?

Comment: @gnat, SriramSakthivel: You are not responsible for other people's votes, and the NAA flag is not an all-purpose "@#$% this" button. Situations like the ones you're describing probably require a custom flag - further evidenced by the fact that the answers in the screenshot were deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @AirThomas ...if seriously, _organic_ protection against turning Stack Exchange into polling device seems to be limited by closing questions where it tend to happen. This works pretty well most of the time but if someone manages to break through and [popularity contest](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/01/the-trouble-with-popularity/ "The Trouble With Popularity") launches, it becomes really hard to cut it off without moderator intervention. Whether NAA is okay to signal this, I can't tell, one advantage it has is that post can gain feedback in LQ review to help moderator decide

Answer (score 41, accepted):

First off, I agree that this question isn't a duplicate of [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-it-is-not-an-answer) - but you should *absolutely* read the answer to that question, as it will save you some amount of frustration in the future.

Now, on to your question...

> Does that means these kind of answers are welcome in Stack Overflow?

No, it doesn't. It means that folks disagreed as to whether or not *this specific answer* should be **removed.** There's a vast difference between "let's not delete this" and "let's roll out the red carpet for anything that looks like this!"

There are plenty of answers that *do* attempt to answer the question asked, *are* technically accurate, but *fail* to actually be of use to folks facing the problem being addressed. The proper action there is usually just to downvote; in extreme cases, moderators and trusted members of the site *can* delete them, but even then they're much more likely to do so if others have previously indicated the worth of the answer by voting. If an answer *that does answer the question* is heavily downvoted but never deleted, it is not a problem; it will be visibly deemphasized by the system in favor of better answers.
See also: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Oh... And get rid of this notion that lackluster answers should be *converted to comments.* The *last* thing we need to be doing with unhelpful posts is pinning them directly under the question, *above* more useful answers. Comments should be reserved for errata, tangential notes, and requests for clarification - and they should usually be seen as temporary. Unhelpful comments cannot be downvoted, just deleted - so if folks disagree about deleting an *answer*, it's a pretty good bet it wouldn't be removed as a *comment*.

Comment: I've read the martin's answer carefully (yours too). There is one confusion still, Do we need to flag a link only answer? I mean literally only link saying *this will help you*? Martin's answer says no(as it is trying to help) and  JanDvorak's comment below the answer says we have to. I tend to flag(ofcourse I downvote) many link only answers and they will be eventually deleted. We need to flag such answers or not?

Comment: "Link only" is a fairly useless classification: answers that actually contain *nothing* but a link are pretty rare, so what you're really asking is "what besides a link must an answer contain to be considered an answer?" I answer *that* question here: [When is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: Following this idea an answer of the kind:"No, check this out (random url)" would be perfectly right. Yet in my opinion those answers do not contribute to StackOverflow. I thought the idea of an Q&A site is to give the OP and FUTURE visitors information they need. Shouldn't we try to elaborate our answers then and try to give a generalized solution?

Comment: Ask yourself, @theminion, ["Would this be an answer *without* the link?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Comment: I mostly agree with this, though I'd like to point out that, if I'd encountered this answer in *any* moderator queue, I would very likely have deleted it (even if someone NAA'd it), since it looks more like a comment to me than an answer (and a very uninformative one at that).

Comment: @theminion it would be an answer: it says "no" (assuming the question was something along the lines of "can X be done?").  It isn't a **good** answer, but it does answer the question.  "Check this out (random url)" is not-an-answer, because without the link it says nothing.  So by my reading, the right thing to do is downvote, not flag-for-not-an-answer.